# Updating progressbar in AsyncTask doInBackground()?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

One of the first things I learned when beginning android development (and beginners development in general) is that the UI should not (and in many cases can not) be updated by any other thread besides the main UI thread.

I have an AsyncTask that is moving a bunch of files in its doInBackground().  I have a progressbar that represents that to the user.

For the heck of it (mostly due to laziness) I decided to try the progressBar.setProgress([updated progress]) right in the doInBackground() method/thread, and to my surprise, it works fine.

However, that seems to go against the convention I've learned.  I know AsyncTask has a onProgressUpdate() or whatever, but it's confusing me a bit, and I'm not sure if it's worth switching, since the current implementation seems to be working fine.

Should I not be updating the progressbar in this background thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ProgressBar`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java) is able to do this without crashing because `setProgress()` calls `refreshProgress()` (a Thread-safe method), when it is time to actually refresh the View.

```
private synchronized void refreshProgress(int id, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (mUiThreadId == Thread.currentThread().getId()) {
            doRefreshProgress(id, progress, fromUser, true);
        } else {
            if (mRefreshProgressRunnable == null) {
                mRefreshProgressRunnable = new RefreshProgressRunnable();
            }

            final RefreshData rd = RefreshData.obtain(id, progress, fromUser);
            mRefreshData.add(rd);
            if (mAttached && !mRefreshIsPosted) {
                post(mRefreshProgressRunnable);
                mRefreshIsPosted = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

It posts a `Runnable` to the UI Thread if the method call was made a **non-UI** Thread, avoiding `CalledFromWrongThreadException`s.

However, *always* use the UI thread for UI related calls; the Android developers can change the implementation anytime and Views are usually not Thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify the `ProgressBar` and/or call any of its methods directly from inside `doInBackground()`, as the Android UI toolkit is not thread safe.

Instead, call `publishProgress()` from inside `doInBackground()` and you will receive a subsequent callback on the UI thread in `onProgressUpdate()` where you can modify the `ProgressBar` however you like.

Comment: Did you mean `publishProgress()` instead of `refreshProgress()`?